# Npgsql - NOTIFY event and attach a payload

Tags: postgresql, asp.net-core, npgsql

Is it possible to receive a payload when using the `NOTIFY` psql method?

right now Im using

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("NOTIFY test", conn)) {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

but I would like to attach a message with the `NOTIFY` event

**to clarify**

```
using (var cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("NOTIFY test_channel, test_message", conn)) {
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

this throws an error

```
Exception has occurred: CLR/Npgsql.PostgresException
An exception of type 'Npgsql.PostgresException' 
occurred in System.Private.CoreLib.dll 
but was not handled in user code: 'External component has thrown an exception.'
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete exception (with message and stack trace)?

Answer (score -1):

[As the PostgreSQL docs shows](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-notify.html), you can include an arbitrary payload string:

> NOTIFY test, payload